# I'm trying to use useEffect' for changing window. I do not get any error, but it doesn't work. What is wrong? How to make it work?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, use-effect

Through dropzone, I'm uploading or dropping files.
What I want to do is to open a new window type, based on the file type that has been dropped.
To accomplish this, I'm trying to use the useEffect hook. But it doesn't produce  any error and doesn't work:

```
const [win, setWin] = useState("A-Type");

let accepted_file = acceptedFiles[0];

useEffect(() => {
  function handleSecondWindowType () {
    if (accepted_file.type.includes('image/')) {
      setWin("A-Type")
    }
    else {
      setWin("B-Type");
    }
  }
},[accepted_file]);
```

Comment: Why have you declared the function `handleSecondWindowType`? Simply remove the declaration and do what you want to do in between the `() => { ... }`. Or just call it.

Comment: Yes. That's a possible solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have created an internal function but forgot to call it. You have to call it or nothing happened:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // call it
  handleSecondWindowType();

  function handleSecondWindowType () {
    if (accepted_file.type.includes('image/')) {
      setWin("A-Type")
    }
    else {
      setWin("B-Type");
    }
  }
},[accepted_file]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it like tmhao2005 said, or just remove the additional function declaration.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (accepted_file.type.includes('image/')) {
      setWin("A-Type")
    }
    else {
      setWin("B-Type");
    }
}, [accepted_file]);
```

Another possibility would be this:

```js
function handleSecondWindowType() {
    if (accepted_file.type.includes('image/')) {
      setWin("A-Type")
    }
    else {
      setWin("B-Type");
    }
}

useEffect(handleSecondWindowType, [accepted_file]);
```